# Accuracy percent seems too high in Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy

I built an artificial neural network that has a dependent variable called "Suspicious".  This column is binary so only two outcomes.  I have 297,771 "0" not suspicious or known good.  Then I have only 1,100 rows in my data labeled as "1" for suspicious or bad.  After the test set the confusion matrix looks like this:

```
cm
array([[59552, 0],
       [148,  75]])
```

This gives me a test accuracy of 99.75240%.  This seems way too high.  Is there a rule of thumb for how many bad or "1's" I should have in the data before I run it though the model, like 1/3, or 1/2?

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312780/why-is-accuracy-not-the-best-measure-for-assessing-classification-models

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were a naive prediction model, based on the overall distribution of data, I would likely guess "$0$" for every single outcome.  This would give me an accuracy of:

$$
\frac{297771}{297771+1100} = 0.9963195 = 99.63195\% \text{ accuracy}
$$

Based on this, your prediction model is only *marginally* better than a naive estimator which assumes all outputs are $0$.  Food for thought.

Comment: I guess I will increase  the "1" observations in my dataset and run it again.

Comment: If you are able to do so easily, that would probably be a good idea!